# Web Service returning same values FLEX 4.6

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, resultevent

Hi i trying to fill a datagrid with values i previously inserted in flex app,
but i geting the same value as the first insert and the second, third, fourth inserts are happening, but flex is bringing the same value. Any idea about? Code above:

```
<s:HTTPService id="findPpl" url="http://server.com.br/requests/phprequest.php" useProxy="false" method="GET" result="findPpl_resultHandler(event)">
        <s:request xmlns="">
        <database>{Banco}</database>
        <function>findppl</function>
        <ID>{lastID}</ID>
    </s:request>
</s:HTTPService>
```

The result event code is here:

```
    protected function findPpl_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(event.result.request.pplis ArrayCollection){
                pplDp = event.result.request.ppl;
            }
            if(event.result.request.ppl is ObjectProxy){
                pplDp  = new ArrayCollection(ArrayUtil.toArray(event.result.request.ppl));
            }


        }
```

Whatever i change this returning the same Objectproxy, dont matter if i make 3 more inserts, if somebody mind something pls help! Ty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refreshing an XML file through HTTPService in Flex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686161/refreshing-an-xml-file-through-httpservice-in-flex)

Comment: See the answer to the question mentioned above - this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on your browser, it could be that the results of the first request are being cached by it. If you have control over the service, you could set the headers to expire. You can also try by passing a parameter in the URL that changes with every request (for example `?dummy-parameter=<a-time-dependent-string>`)

Comment: Eduardo, i tryed that and i got no results, i think is on flex the "thing" because i run the code from php on browser and i got the result i was expecting on flex.